# Getting Text Values in ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Working on an exercise from [Angular in Action](http://www.manning.com/bford/), I'm trying to add functionality to add a new "story".

In the following code, I'm trying to create a "newStory" by adding to the `stories` array with a **title** and **description** equal to the current text in the relevant textfields.

**app.html**

```
    <div class="controls">
        <button id="addStory"
                    class="medium-btn"
                    type="button"
                ng-click="addNewStory(getNewStoryTitle(), getNewStoryDesc()">
    </button>
```

**app.js**

```
myModule.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) { 
    $scope.newStoryTitle;
    $scope.newStoryDesc;

    $scope.getNewStoryTitle = function() { 
        return $scope.newStoryTitle;
    };

    $scope.getNewStoryDesc = function() { 
        return $scope.newStoryDesc;
    };

    $scope.stories = [
            {title: 'Story 00', description: 'Description pending.'},
                        ...
        ];

    $scope.createStory = function(t, d) { 
        const newStory = [{title: t, description: d}];
        $scope.stories = Array.prototype.concat($scope.stories, newStory);
    };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S5ma7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated the fiddle, mostly fixing errors. The approach is correct, only some minor fixes were required - http://jsfiddle.net/S5ma7/7/

As SO requires code being pasted here:

```
var myModule = angular.module('Angello', []);

myModule.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.currentStory = null;
    $scope.newStoryTitle = '';
    $scope.newStoryDesc = '';

    $scope.setCurrentStory = function (story) {
        $scope.currentStory = story;
    };

    $scope.getNewStoryTitle = function () {
        return $scope.newStoryTitle;
    };

    $scope.getNewStoryDesc = function () {
        return $scope.newStoryDesc;
    };

    $scope.stories = [{
        title: 'Story 00',
        description: 'Description pending.'
    }, {
        title: 'Story 01',
        description: 'Description pending.'
    }, {
        title: 'Story 02',
        description: 'Description pending.'
    }, {
        title: 'Story 03',
        description: 'Description pending.'
    }, {
        title: 'Story 04',
        description: 'Description pending.'
    }, {
        title: 'Story 05',
        description: 'Description pending.'
    }];

    $scope.addNewStory = function (t, d) {
        $scope.stories.push({
            title: t,
            description: d
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for fixing my errors. Overall, could you give me your opinion on the `$scope.getNewStoryTitle` and `$scope.getNewStoryDesc` methods? Are they idiomatic Angular?

Comment: As you see this methods currently do nothing except returning state property. So unless you have a quite strong reason to do so (some logging, transformation, etc) it is nothing prevents from removing them.

Answer (score 1):

Do not know if it's part of the exercise, but can be made much simpler.

You can declare your model with the ng-model attribute and then you only need a method to add it to your collection. Something like this:

```
 <form>
   <div>
     <label for="inputTitle">Title</label>
     <input type="text" id="inputTitle" placeholder="Title" ng-model="newStory.title">
   </div>
   <div>
     <label for="inputDescription">Description</label>
     <textarea id="inputDescription" placeholder="Description" rows="3" ng-model="newStory.description"></textarea>
   </div>
   <div>
     <button ng-click="addStory(newStory)">Add Story</button>
   </div>
  </form>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.stories = [];

$scope.addStory = function(story) {
    $scope.stories.push(story);
};
```

I hope this help: http://jsfiddle.net/S5ma7/8/